# playing youtube music in universal C#

Tags: c#, youtube-api, win-universal-app

I'm making an app for windows phone using windows universal. The app will play music from disk and stream music from a link. My users want to be able to take a youtube link and stream the music of the video on their phone.

Is this possible?

I am using the [Backgroundmediaplayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playback.backgroundmediaplayer) to be able to turn the screen off and still keep it playing. Basicaly, I need to convert a youtube link into a valid [MediaSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.core.mediasource).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from @thomas-lebrun's answer, based on the [ToS of YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms?hl=fr), its prohibited to separate the audo and video components of any content.

> separate, isolate, or modify the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API;

Comment: It's a shame... understandable, but a shame.
Thanks for your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Youtube does not allow to get the direct link of music/video to use them. You need to use a Webview to display your content but, in case of a video, you might get the ads that appear before the real video.